f is a real valued additive function, locally integrable on R , then f is a linear function
$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$
$f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
P.T: there exists some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= cx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
MY APPROACH
As $f$ is additive function , it's suggests that $f(1)$ can be $c$
$f(x)= xf(1)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$
after this , I don't know how to use the locally integrable criteria and prove the rest.
Thanks in advance.

Any measurable additive map on $\mathbb R$ is linear.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation
